# Does my yeast possibly already have yeast nutrient?

Tags: yeast-nutrient

I forgot to buy some yeast nutrient.

But maybe it's already in the yeast?

Vinter's Harvest : Premium Wine Yeast

Ingredients: Dried Yeeast, emulsifier, magnesium, sulphate, trace vitamins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say "no". It's in quotes because all yeast nutrient is is dehydrated empty yeast cells. So, I guess you could say that "yes" there is yeast nutrient in all yeast. Your ingredients say it includes trace vitamins though so perhaps they put a little yeast nutrient in with it? I will say that if you're properly sanitized and the yeast you're using is relatively fresh, you're probably okay to ferment without adding yeast nutrient. It's still not too late to sprinkle a little yeast nutrient if it makes you feel better about it.

Next time, to be sure you have viable and healthy yeast, I would always make a starter.

Comment: Most dry yeast is coated with nutrients.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comments, to err on the safe side I've now added yeast nutrient.

Comment: Great! Happy Brewing!

Answer (score 0):

Are you making wine or beer?  If beer, nutrient isn't a big necessity.  There are a lot of nutrients from the grain, so using additional nutrient isn't a really big deal.  For wine, I don't know.  This is a homebrewing group so wine is kind of outside of our knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

For wine, you typically need to add Ammonium Diphosphate to make up for the lacking nitrogen in must. As Denny said, this is not necessary with beer since wort made from grain is full of the stuff.

Be sure to oxygenate or airate as well as you can, and this will go some way to offsetting the low levels of nutrients. Alternatively, add the nutrients a few days later.

The yeast ingredients list metals and trace vitamins, which are also a form of nutrient. So your yeast isn't totally nutrient free, so you can probably just go ahead and use it, following any instructions on the packet regarding rehydration.